# How to start array at negative indices C#(UNITY)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Hi i am very new to c# programming i just want to ask if there's a way to start an index to negative 1?

here's my code

```
string[,] table = new string[104, 15];
int xIndex = -1;
int yIndex = 0;

if(table.GetLength(0) < xIndex){
    break;
}

if (result.Equals(newPrevious) || result.Equals("A") && yIndex <  table.GetLength(1))
{
    yIndex += 1;
    table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
}
else
{
    xIndex += 1;
    yIndex = 0;
    table [xIndex, yIndex] = result;
}
previous = result ;

if (!result.Equals("A"))
{
     newPrevious = previous;
}
```

It is giving me an error here

```
if (result.Equals(newPrevious) || result.Equals("A") && yIndex <  table.GetLength(1))
{
    yIndex += 1;
    table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;   //<---- ERROR HERE
}
```

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.

## EDIT

I'll explain what i am doing . I am creating a scoreboard for my game and this `xIndex` and `yIndex` serves as the position of my object inside of my scoreboard like this

for example i have this value on my `string[] strData = {"A  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,C  ,C  ,C  ,B  ,B  ,A  ,B  ,C  ,A  ,C  "};`

it will give me an `Exception` Error

but if i change my `string[] strData` to this `string[] strData = {"B  ,B  ,B  ,B  ,C  ,C  ,C  ,B  ,B  ,A  ,B  ,C  ,A  ,C  "};`

it will not give me an exception error.

## EDIT 2

Here's my whole code

```
string[,] table = new string[104, 15];
int xIndex = -1;
int yIndex = 0;
string newPrevious = "placeholder";
//C = BLUE, B = RED, A = GREEN
string[] strData = {"A  ,C  ,C  ,C  ,C  ,C  ,C  ,B  ,B  ,A  ,B  ,C  ,A  ,C  "};

//conditions
string[] scoreBoard = new string[]
{"C  ", "B  ", "A  ",
 "C B","B C" };
string OriginalData = "";


void Start(){
    StartCoroutine ("Win_Log");
}

IEnumerator Win_Log(){

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();

    for (int i = 0; i < strData.Length; i++) {
        OriginalData += strData [i];
        OriginalData += ",";
    }
    string[] newNewData = OriginalData.Split (',');
    string result = "";
    string previous = "";

    
    foreach (string newStrData in newNewData) {
        Debug.Log ("This is the data : " + newStrData);

        GameObject o = Instantiate (prefab_gameobject) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent (pos_big_road);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        img = (RawImage)o.GetComponent<RawImage> ();

        //check the length so that it won't throw an exception
        if (newStrData.Length > 1) {
            //get only the first letter of the value A,B,C
            result = newStrData.Substring (0, 1);
        } 
        else {
            result = "";
        }
        
        #region BIG ROAD
        if(table.GetLength(0) < xIndex){
            break;
        }

        if (result.Equals(newPrevious) || result.Equals("A") && yIndex <  table.GetLength(1))
        {
            yIndex += 1;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        else if (result.Equals("A"))
        {
            xIndex += 1;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        else
        {
            xIndex += 1;
            yIndex = 0;
            table [xIndex, yIndex] = result;
        }
        previous = result ;

        if (!result.Equals("A"))
        {
            newPrevious = previous;
        }
```

Here's the output i want to expect

[EXPECTED OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtLw1.png)

But if change the `first string value` to `B or C` its not throwing an exception error.

And as you can see in the image link if the value exceeds from 7 it will move to the x axis but still the same of y axis.

Comment: You can never start array at negative index because array index start from 0.

Comment: Array index starts from 0 in most programming languages. Trying to use index less than 0 or more than the size of the array-1 will give you an error. It's better to explain what you are doing so that people will give you a better workaround.

Comment: @BoonMingProg, Can you share logcat?

Comment: Okay will edit my question

Answer (score 3):

No, arrays index starts at 0.

I'm not sure what is the point to try to have negative indexes, but you can try to emulate it by considering 0 your (minus whatever is your lowest value).